# If minor refers to determinant, then what do you call the matrix? Can I just say 'minor determinant' vs 'minor matrix'?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, determinant, matrix-rank

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285284/rank-k-implies-nonzero-minor-of-size-k-times-k-finding-the-specific-minor), I ask about a proposition (stated below) and in doing so don't use the term 'minor'. What I do is when you delete row k and column $l$, you get a *minor matrix*. It's determinant is a *minor determinant*.

> Proposition. Let $F$ be a field. Let $n \ge 2$ be an integer. For any $A \in F^{n \times n}$ with $rank(A)=k = n-1$, we have that some minor determinant $\det(M_{(i,j)})$ of a minor matrix of $M_{(i,j)}$, of size $k \times k$, is nonzero.

I find it weird that everywhere I've looked so far minor refers to the determinant instead of the matrix and then there's not quite a term for the matrix. What's up with this? Is it wrong/weird if I make up the terms *minor matrix* and *minor determinant*? Is there really no term for those sub-matrices you get when deleting a row and a column from a matrix?

Comment: I think "minor matrix" is fine in this context; it's clear (at least to me) what you mean. You could also try "submatrix" maybe.

Comment: I agree with Dave. I never understood this terminology either.

Comment: @Dave ah i think i get it: we can just say submatrix instead of 'minor matrix' because $k \times k$ submatrix out of an $n \times m$ matrix is always going to be formed out of deleting rows and columns anyway eg $2 \times 2$ submatrix of $3 \times 3$ matrix is formed if and only if you delete 1 row and 1 column so there's not necessarily a need to define 'minor matrix' from the deletion? thanks for commenting!

Comment: @amsmath wait so are you siding with me (minor matrix)? or with most books (that don't really have a term for 'minor matrix' except possibly submatrix) ? (cf my reply to Dave)

Comment: @BCLC I go with you. I would like to call a submatrix 'minor', but I can't due to convention.

Comment: @Dave you can post as answer btw

Comment: I'd recommend “submatrix”. By the way, it might be worth remembering that determinants came before matrices historically, however strange that may seem nowadays. According to the entries for **matrix** and **minor** [here](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/m/), the mathematical meanings of both words were introduced by Sylvester in 1850.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close off the question, here is my comment:

I think "minor matrix" is fine in this context; it's clear (at least to me) what you mean. You could also try "submatrix" maybe.

---

**OP's edit:**

> ah i think i get it: we can just say submatrix instead of 'minor matrix' because k×k submatrix out of an n×m matrix is always going to be formed out of deleting rows and columns anyway eg 2×2 submatrix of 3×3 matrix is formed if and only if you delete 1 row and 1 column so there's not necessarily a need to define 'minor matrix' from the deletion? thanks for commenting!